# Can't access methods on object from array

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to call a method on an object I'm accessing from an array. For some reason, the only methods I can call are methods of the Object class. Help? Here is my code:

```
listItem = findViewById(myResourceId);
TextView itemTextView = ((TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text));
ImageView itemImageView = ((ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail));
ClassMember currentMember = myClassMembers[position];
itemImageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(currentMember.getMemberThumbnailId()));
```

The problem is that I can't call the getMemberThumbnailId on my currentMember object.

Strangely enough, I can get it to work if I do

```
myClassMembers[position].getThumbnailId();
```

instead of

```
ClassMember currentMember = myClassMembers[position];
currentMember.getThumbnailId();
```

Comment: What's the declared type of `myClassMembers[]`.

Comment: The array is probably of objects of type Object.

Comment: Nope. The array is of type ClassMember[]. Still doesn't work.

Comment: The `ClassMember` doesn't declare a method `getMemberThumbnailId`

Comment: Nope. That's not it either.

Comment: @user2733881 That's the only possibility if your `myClassMembers` is of type `ClassMember[]`.

Comment: Not so, my friend. None of my methods for my ClassMember are showing up and I certainly have at least some methods defined for my ClassMember object.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the ClassMember currentMember, then you should be able to have access to the methods you want.

You just need to make sure that your array of Objects that you are accessing is of the right type.  If need be, then do a check on that first.

```
if (currentMember instanceof ClassMember) { 
((ClassMember)currentMember).getMemberThumbnailId();
```

}

Comment: When I cast the currentMember, the compiler tells me that the casting is redundant.

Comment: Interesting, well then if the object list was CurrentMembers then you should see the method available.  If your IDE is not telling you why with the cursor over it I would be surprised.  But often or not this is because it is not the right type...OR...the method is not made with the 'public' attribute and therefore cannot be seen.

Comment: method is public. I'll try restarting my IDE, but I think it might have something to do with how I created the array of ClassMembers. The array is an instance variable that I set equal to another ClassMember array parameter that I get from the constructor. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

How have you declared your array? Have you declared it as:

```
ClassMember myClassMembers = new ClassMember[anInt];
```

or have you declared it as:

```
Object myClassMembers = new Object[anInt];
```

If you have chosen the second option, then you would have to cast the object back to it's original type (`ClassMember`). e.g.

```
ClassMember currentMember = (ClassMember) myClassMembers[position];
```

Another factor may be how you have added `ClassMember` instances to the array itself.

Comment: Here's my declaration:

ClassMember[] myClassMembers;
public ClassListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ClassMember[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            myResourceId = resource;
            myClassMembers = objects;
        }